# How to solve a system of first order linear differential equations of two variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on a physics problem when I encountered the following system of DE.
$$\epsilon - i_2R_2-L_2\frac{\mathrm{d}i_2}{\mathrm{dt}}=r(i_1+i_2)$$
$$\epsilon - i_1R_1-L_1\frac{\mathrm{d}i_1}{\mathrm{dt}}=r(i_1+i_2)$$
I need to find $i_1 , i_2$ as a function of time.
I looked up on internet to see how can we solve such problems but these variables are making it insane for me to actually solve.
I know how to solve linear DEs but only in one variable.
Any help/approach to this problem would be very much helpful!

Comment: Why do you think it is nonlinear?

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear ODE, but you are given a $2 \times 2$ system of linear ODEs. We can apply linear algebra method by expressing the above equations in state-space representation.

Equation 1:
$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon - R_2i_2 - L_2 \dot{i_2} & = r(i_1 +i_2) \\
\iff L_2 \dot{i_2} & = \epsilon - ri_1 -(R_2 + r)i_2\\
\iff \dot{i_2} & = \frac{\epsilon}{L_2} - \frac{r}{L_2}i_1 - \frac{R_2 + r}{L_2}i_2\\
\end{align}
$$

Equation 2:
$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon - R_1i_1 - L_1 \dot{i_1} & = r(i_1 +i_2) \\
\iff L_1 \dot{i_1} & = \epsilon - (R_1 + r)i_1 - ri_2 \\
\iff \dot{i_1} & = \frac{\epsilon}{L_1} - \frac{R_1 + r}{L_1}i_1 - \frac{r}{L_1}i_2 \\
\end{align}
$$

Hence, we can express the above equations in the form $\dot{x} =Ax+bv$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{i_1} \\
\dot{i_2} \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R_1 + r}{L_1} & -\frac{r}{L_1} \\
-\frac{r}{L_2} & -\frac{R_2 + r}{L_2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
i_1 \\
i_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\epsilon}{L_1} \\
\frac{\epsilon}{L_2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $v=1$.

The general solution to the $2 \times 2$ inhomogeneous system of linear ODE is given by:
$$
x=e^{At}x_0 + \int_{0}^{t}e^{A(t-\tau)}bvd\tau
$$
for $x_0 = x(0) $.

You can diagonalize your matrix $A$, and compute the corresponding eigenvalues and eigenvectors to find your fundamental matrix $e^{At}$. After that, you can compute the integral portion due to the forced response of your system, given by the vector $b$.

The computation of your solution will be very tedious due to the algebraic expression. That's all. Hope it helps.

Comment: can we maybe calculate it through wolfram alpha? Also another important info maybe that I need value of functions as t tends infinity. So any way of doing it without solving the thing you proposed?

Comment: 1. Well... you can do that, or even script it on MATLAB if you have the exact values to $\epsilon, r, R_1, R_2, L_1$ and $L_2$ to investigate the dynamics of the system visually. If you want to solve $i_1(t)$ and $i_2(t)$ and retain the algebraic terms, you really have to work with them unfortunately.

Comment: 2. For $t \rightarrow \infty$, the system will be in the steady state. This statement directly translates to $\frac{di_1}{dt} = \frac{di_2}{dt} = 0 $. Hence, you can just solve for your steady-state values by finding $i_{1\infty}$ and $i_{2\infty}$ respectively:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R_1 + r}{L_1} & -\frac{r}{L_1} \\
-\frac{r}{L_2} & -\frac{R_2 + r}{L_2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{1\infty} \\
i_{2\infty} \\
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\epsilon}{L_1} \\
\frac{\epsilon}{L_2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$